# Using database's elements for updating elements in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Here's my code:

```js
db.findOneAndUpdate({}, {$inc:{'counter': 1}}, (err) => {
        if (err){
            res.status(400).json('error')
        }
    })
    
    db.findOneAndUpdate({id: req.body.id}, {$push: {
        elementsArray: {
            nev: req.body.nev,
            id: //db.counter
        }
    }})
```

What i want to do here is that when the server gets a post request from the front end, increment the counter, so every element will get an unique id. My problem is that i can't assign the new counter value to the new element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chain the two requests using `new: true` option to get back the modified document holding the counter

```js
function updateCounter() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.findOneAndUpdate({}, {
      $inc: {
        counter: 1,
      },
    }, {
      // get you the updated document
      new: true,
    }, (err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      return resolve(doc);
    });
  });
}

function updateOther(counter) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.findOneAndUpdate({
      id: req.body.id,
    }, {
      $push: {
        elementsArray: {
          nev: req.body.nev,
          id: counter,
        },
      },
    }, (err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      return resolve(doc);
    });
  });
}

// First update the counter
// Then update your other stuff using the counter info
updateCounter()
  .then(doc => updateOther(doc.counter))
  .then(() => {
    // Done
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.status(400).json('error');
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately the id of the pushed element is null. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't saw that I had forgot to pass the counter to the function. My bad, glad you did figure it out by yourself :)